Understanding uriTemplate and Variable IDs in Symfony API Platform
I'm currently working on a Symfony project using API Platform, and I'm running into some confusion regarding the uriTemplate system and how it handles variable IDs.
I have an entity called Article, and I want to set up a custom collection route that uses a parameter other than {id}. Specifically, I want to use {categoryId}. However, I'm encountering issues when I try to do this, and I'm not sure why API Platform seems to insist on using {id}.
Here is an example of my Article entity configuration:
<?php
use ApiPlatform\Metadata\ApiResource;
use ApiPlatform\Metadata\Get;
use ApiPlatform\Metadata\GetCollection;
use App\State\ArticlesByCategoryProvider;

#[ApiResource(
    operations: [
        new Get(
            uriTemplate: '/{id}',
            requirements: ['id' => '\d+']
        ),
        new GetCollection(
            uriTemplate: '/categories/{categoryId}',
            provider: ArticlesByCategoryProvider::class
        )
    ],
    routePrefix: '/articles',
    normalizationContext: ['groups' => ['articles_read']],
    denormalizationContext: ['groups' => ['articles_write']]
)]
class Article
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    #[Groups(['articles_read'])]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
    #[Groups(['articles_read', 'articles_write'])]
    private ?string $title = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'text')]
    #[Groups(['articles_read', 'articles_write'])]
    private ?string $content = null;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: Category::class)]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: false)]
    #[Groups(['articles_read', 'articles_write'])]
    private ?Category $category = null;

    // Other fields and methods...
}

The issue
When I try to access /api/articles/categories/{categoryId}, it seems that API Platform tries to resolve {categoryId} as if it were an id for the Article entity itself, leading to this error :

"Invalid identifier value or configuration."

I was able to solve my problem by putting /categories/{id}, but I would like to know if we can get around that, knowing that I can have several entities in the URL, for example /categories/{categoryId}/tags/{tagId}.
Questions

Why does API Platform enforce using {id}?
Is there a way to use a different parameter like {categoryId} in the uriTemplate?
How can I configure my routes and providers to work with a parameter other than {id}?

Any insights or examples would be greatly appreciated!

Up! very good question, noted for myself to make a research

I faced same issue and found that using custom var name is possible by using uriVariable attribute.
uriTemplate: '/categories/{categoryId}',
uriVariables: ['categoryId'],

